# Handling dependent entities when deleting the principal with Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Here's the situation in its most simplified form using the EF5 Code-First approach:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<PK>
{
    public PK ID { get; set; }
}
public class Country : EntityBase<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Address : EntityBase<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    // ... other address properties ...
}
```

The one-to-many relationship between `Address` and `Country` is set up with no cascade-delete like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Country)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Finally, I have a generic base repository class with CRUD methods that call `SaveChanges` on the underlying DbContext to commit data changes atomically. E.g.:

```
public class EFRepository<T, PK> : IRepository<T, PK> where T : EntityBase<PK>
{
    //
    // ... other methods ... 
    //
    public virtual void Delete(T instance)
    {
        // ... trigger validations, write to log, etc...
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Remove(instance);
        try
        {
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ... handle the error ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Part 1:**

Scenario:

```
var countryRepo = new EFRepository<Country>();
var country = countryRepo.Save(new Country() { ID="??", Name="Test Country" });

var addressRepo = new EFRepository<Address>();
var address = addressRepo.Save(new Address() { Country=country });

countryRepo.Delete(country);
```

This should fail due to the existence of a dependent `Address`. However, afterwards the address ends up with a null in `CountryID`, which is invalid because `Address.CountryID` is required, so subsequent `SaveChanges` calls throw a validation exception unless the address is detached.

I expected that when an object is deleted, EF5 will be smart enough to first check for any cascade-delete constraints like the one above and, failing to find any, then proceed to delete the data. But exactly the opposite seems to be the case.

Is this a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

**Part 2:**

Following a failed `SaveChanges` call, some `Addresses` are now in an invalid state in my DbContext and need to be restored to their original values. Of course, I can always do so explicitly for each entity type (`Country`, `State`, `Order`, etc.) by creating specialized repository classes and overriding `Delete`, but it smells big time. I'd much rather write some general purpose code to gracefully recover related entities after a failed  `SaveChanges` call.

It would require interrogating DbContext to get all relationships in which an entity (e.g. `Country`) is the principal, regardless of whether or not its class defines navigational properties to dependent entities.

E.g. `Country` has no `Addresses` property, so I need to somehow find in DbContext the definition of the one-to-many relationship between `Country` and `Address` and use it to restore all related `Addresses` to their original values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in **Part 2**:

Here is my approach to checking for related dependents when deleting an entity on the principal end of a many-to-one relationship and where dependents are NOT exposed as a navigation collection in the principal (e.g. class `Address` has a `Country` property, but class `Country` doesn't have an `Addresses` collection).

*DbContext*

Add the following method to the context class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an array of entities tracked by the 
/// context that satisfy the filter criteria.
/// </summary>
public DbEntityEntry[] GetTrackedEntities<T>(
    Expression<Func<DbEntityEntry<T>, bool>> filterCriteria) 
    where T : class
{
    var result = new List<DbEntityEntry>();
    var doesItMatch = filterCriteria.Compile();

    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>())
    {
        if (doesItMatch(entry))
            result.Add(entry);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

*Repositories*

Create a repository for each class that has some dependencies, override the `Delete` method and use the new `GetTrackedEntities<T>` method to get all related dependents and either:

- explicitly delete them if they are cascade-deletable in code
- detach them from the context if they are cascade-deletable in the DB itself
- throw an exception if they are NOT cascade-deletable.

Example of the latter case:

```
public class EFCountryRepository : 
    EFReadWriteRepository<Country, string>, 
    ICountryRepository 
{
    public override void Delete(Country instance)
    {
        // Allow the Country to be deleted only if there are no dependent entities
        // currently in the context that are NOT cascade-deletable.
        if (
            // are there any Regions in the context that belong to this Country?
            _dbContext.GetTrackedEntities<Region>(e => 
                e.Entity.CountryID == instance.ID || 
                e.Entity.Country == instance).Length > 0  
            ||
            // are there any Addresses in the context that belong to this Country?
            _dbContext.GetTrackedEntities<Address>(e =>
                e.Entity.CountryID == instance.ID || 
                e.Entity.Country == instance).Length > 0
        )
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
                "Country '{0}' is in use and cannot be deleted.", instance.ID));

        base.Delete(instance);
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

Example of a case where cascade-deleting will be done by the DB itself, so all we need to do is detach the dependents from the context:

```
public class EFOrderRepository : 
    EFReadWriteRepository<Order, string>, 
    IOrderRepository 
{
    public override void Delete(Order instance)
    {
        foreach (var orderItem in _dbContext.GetTrackedEntities<OrderItem>(e => 
                e.Entity.OrderID == instance.ID || 
                e.Entity.Order == instance))
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(orderItem).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
        }
        base.Delete(instance);
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

Hope someone will find this solution helpful.